# Apache Storm integration with kafka exception ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy at

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to integrate Apache Storm with kafka. When I am running the code, I am getting the spout and bolts created. When I click on the spout, I getting the following error in the errors tab:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy 
at  storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:68) 
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4949$fn__4964.invoke(executor.clj:542)
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:463) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.RetryPolicy 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) 
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ... 5 more
```

I am using sandbox VM of hortonworks and I tried copying the curator test, client and framworks(all 2.4.0) versions in the lib folder of Storm, but the problem is still coming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The curator client jar is not present in your classpath Have a look at this link

https://github.com/abhinavg6/Kafka-Storm-Conscomp/issues/1

Comment: I tried copying curator-client-2.4.0.jar into the storm/lib directory, its still throwing the same error .

Comment: did you add com.google.guava, and org.apache.zookeeper as well after adding the curator-client jar as its given in the post.